# Tomcat 7.0.75 @PostConstruct not called

Tags: java, tomcat, dependency-injection, tomcat7, postconstruct

I updated form Tomcat 7.0.40 to Tomcat 7.0.75 and my application crashes with null pointer exception because the injected objects are not being initialized.
The objects are declared as @Named and @ApplicationScoped. They also contains a @PostConstruct init() method.

This behavior only occurs with the new Tomcat.

Does anybody else have this issue and a possible solution?

Thank you very much!